# I am creating a Custom button with add functionality

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, salesforce1-app, dynamic-vf-component

In a visualforce page with two different components a & b, i want to create an add button which adds fields from component A and add it to the fields on component B while creating a record on component B.

both these components have same field name 
                                                        (ADD)

```
Component a(object 1)      Component b (object 2) 
FIELD 1                    FIELD 1 
FIELD 2                    FIELD 2 
FIELD 3                    FIELD 3  
FIELD 4                    FIELD 4 
START DATE/TIME            START DATE/TIME            
END DATE/TIME              END DATE/TIME
```

the add button has to pickup the field values from component A and add it to Component b.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange, can you share a little bit of information about what you have researched and tried so far perhaps? For example have you looked through the Developer guide for Apex and Visualforce? This will help people gauge the level of answer to be given.

Comment: As a starting point i would perhaps create a Visualforce page using the Standard Controller for Object B, place the button on Object B's custom layout. When button is clicked, using the 'action' on the page, to run some code to read the related Object A record, apply the additions to Object B's fields (loaded via the Standard Controller) and present a summary to the user of the resulting state of Object B's fields, before allowing them to press a button that is bound to the Standard Controller 'save' method.

Comment: Hi Andrew Fawcett. Thank you for the reply. I have created a Visualforce page for object 1 and 2 . Actually its one page with two components and three objects. There are a set of fields in component a which once selected and clicked add should be populated to the component b which has the same set of fields.

Comment: Product_Code__c
Item_Name__c
Line_Description__c
Quantity__c
Sales_Price__c           
Discount__c
Total_Price__c
Start__c
End__c

Comment: These are the fields displayed in table format . the blocker is i am not good at writing code. so can you please atleast guide me as to how to go about it or give me a bit of code to start on. Thanks a ton

Comment: If you post your Visualforce page code that would help, though if your skills at present are not good at writing code, this might not be the best place to start to learn coding, the questions tend to be more specific. Post your code, I'll see if I can get you started with a skeleton peace of code and some links to the developer guides or developer.force.com wiki, have you read these yet btw?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't that comfortable writing code, you should look into using Salesforce Flow rather than Visualforce with Apex.  Flow would let you provide one input form and write the data input to as many Salesforce objects as needed, no controllers necessary.